# Explain fst_posmode, difference between F_PEOFPOSMODE and F_VOLPOSMODE?

Tags: macos, bsd, fcntl

Header file:

```
/* Position Modes (fst_posmode) for F_PREALLOCATE */

#define F_PEOFPOSMODE 3         /* Make it past all of the SEEK pos modes so that */
                    /* we can keep them in sync should we desire */ 
#define F_VOLPOSMODE    4       /* specify volume starting postion */
```

Man page:

```
The position modes (fst_posmode) for the F_PREALLOCATE command indicate how to use the offset field. 

The modes are as follows:
     F_PEOFPOSMODE   Allocate from the physical end of file.
     F_VOLPOSMODE    Allocate from the volume offset.
```

The doc is hard to understand.